# NOKIA Here API error reading KML files

Tags: kml, here-api

Hi i have some problems with reading kml files with nokia here javascript api.

When i read this file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">     
 <Document> <Style id="gitesdegaule.fr"> <LineStyle>

                   <color>30939a9a</color>
                   <width>3</width>
                   </LineStyle>
                   <PolyStyle>
                   <color>2166738f</color>
                   </PolyStyle>
       </Style>

               <Style id="karamelise.fr"></Style>

       <Placemark id="ain"> <name><![CDATA[TOTO]]></name>

                  <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
               <type><![CDATA[dep]]></type>
       <styleUrl>#gitesdegaule.fr</styleUrl> 
<Polygon> 
<outerBoundaryIs>
 <LinearRing>    <tessellate>1</tessellate> <coordinates>

                              4.25890083,44.2644249 4.27377272,44.27175247 4.28899552,44.29214557 4.2883746,44.31501932 4.30211262,44.3148215 4.31809777,44.32175218 4.32925707,44.33237613 4.32577135,44.33832401 4.37017129,44.34013872 4.38705008,44.34705752 4.39560189,44.34432052 4.40234672,44.33500676 4.40145004,44.32816699 4.39159418,44.30475879 4.39331281,44.29459994 4.40357008,44.28817655 4.43198335,44.28968263 4.43560755,44.28332442 4.44042244,44.28342347 4.45321198,44.29786669 4.44875741,44.2967101 4.4510679,44.33409577 4.45534071,44.34026942 4.46476061,44.34167492 4.48291043,44.33819967 4.50609709,44.3402525 4.5120143,44.33539966 4.51473139,44.32911411 4.52416664,44.32876769 4.53115207,44.32409707 4.54911036,44.32451183 4.54774877,44.32287442 4.54563073,44.31970808 4.55716755,44.30416797 4.56999757,44.2993489 4.5742736,44.30074626 4.59898027,44.29175565 4.60546546,44.2910399 4.61662522,44.27799282 4.63267924,44.28499404 4.64922367,44.27035991 4.65236385,44.29127223 4.65318138,44.29480723 4.65061501,44.32980583 4.64958991,44.3342329 4.64683712,44.34828355 4.64906437,44.373073 4.6643734,44.39894431 4.66305349,44.40702263 4.66710646,44.42991215 4.67597774,44.43670158 4.68928691,44.44051412 4.69528931,44.44579734 4.70041036,44.46939017 4.69953724,44.48008255 4.68941493,44.49234869 4.68788192,44.50293409 4.69310072,44.51670268 4.70312868,44.52456221 4.70658782,44.53407141 4.70297307,44.5360992 4.69244606,44.5465171 4.69573855,44.56307077 4.7047198,44.56351778 4.70640399,44.57631421 4.71087231,44.58199901 4.73286442,44.5858884 4.74116893,44.58877439 4.74420238,44.6008919 4.74040454,44.60239253 4.75242599,44.61893344 4.75808936,44.63073891 4.7729024,44.64263201 4.77907273,44.65469864 4.77673911,44.66391226 4.78221009,44.67252315 4.78158975,44.6788457 4.77196818,44.70599753 4.76422013,44.71502737 4.76402727,44.72902451 4.76415967,44.73203915 4.75950659,44.74847569 4.76932099,44.75958502 4.76103981,44.77121674 4.76177186,44.77360052 4.766536,44.77876582 4.78364702,44.78407517 4.79553544,44.79404144 4.79723182,44.80398306 4.8009896,44.80598437 4.80028196,44.81232676 4.80838187,44.8147796 4.82148517,44.81738395 4.82028053,44.83019175 4.82331588,44.83948982 4.83714704,44.841315 4.84411874,44.84546809 4.84394599,44.8556295 4.84998355,44.86479604 4.85676388,44.86955502 4.86128123,44.87822412 4.85432388,44.89652349 4.85757558,44.90289042 4.86863374,44.90960356 4.87108518,44.91622677 4.8865893,44.93665167 4.88136574,44.94460258 4.87427693,44.95636728 4.86048968,44.96555094 4.85308346,44.97790496 4.85256634,44.97953468 4.85186781,44.99372206 4.84249322,45.00198327 4.8367081,45.00750964 4.84540845,45.01995643 4.84411146,45.02337328 4.83989769,45.02885577 4.84194822,45.0379092 4.85410151,45.0462545 4.86074607,45.05542925 4.85359027,45.0638074 4.83583061,45.06827143 4.82915533,45.07284837 4.82781649,45.07855334 4.83046151,45.08402181 4.82959678,45.09800491 4.82502352,45.10398808 4.81478686,45.11145936 4.80403837,45.12246847 4.80383317,45.1291185 4.80413152,45.13126621 4.82857463,45.15423999 4.82871285,45.15612909 4.82409409,45.16125735 4.81183712,45.16525777 4.8102409,45.17492963 4.81168613,45.1837596 4.80585707,45.19175277 4.80587969,45.19757063 4.81220845,45.20495255 4.80320777,45.22527297 4.80163383,45.24599555 4.80884632,45.25884864 4.80998663,45.26647685 4.80961285,45.26950014 4.80948887,45.28768669 4.80049393,45.2983607 4.78154097,45.30987747 4.7622144,45.3235494 4.76083371,45.33641464 4.76104923,45.33838372 4.76334552,45.34435503 4.76771073,45.34386288 4.77374811,45.34815367 4.77255147,45.3542972 4.75599728,45.3656813 4.72582584,45.36180909 4.72311135,45.35460056 4.70331032,45.34956262 4.69802319,45.34498654 4.68012988,45.34626522 4.63855316,45.32619375 4.64317694,45.31890286 4.6338438,45.31494163 4.61579882,45.31025919 4.61699707,45.30009181 4.62291558,45.29473743 4.62159418,45.29142427 4.6118888,45.29202388 4.59859706,45.28948575 4.59134794,45.27288266 4.59849348,45.26897113 4.60530462,45.26366797 4.60531508,45.25340079 4.58480191,45.24407499 4.5610247,45.24721951 4.54255203,45.24218046 4.53625982,45.23681852 4.51811524,45.24174958 4.50559101,45.23303018 4.49078404,45.23221104 4.48313462,45.23644652 4.48891797,45.2234192 4.48606534,45.21679286 4.48132761,45.21591918 4.476933,45.21067296 4.48055542,45.19545926 4.472579,45.17989475 4.46037636,45.17536308 4.45815694,45.16887199 4.44811122,45.16196037 4.4435648,45.14217993 4.44640633,45.13249815 4.45583873,45.12536009 4.4572857,45.11889321 4.46302519,45.10199568 4.44201443,45.11168919 4.43642476,45.10945593 4.4278427,45.117509 4.42949496,45.13039273 4.41115875,45.14082946 4.39782805,45.13948437 4.37655894,45.14435963 4.37257036,45.12807293 4.39967013,45.11498443 4.39713717,45.10523632 4.38458474,45.10107033 4.37146751,45.10438434 4.35923214,45.09957225 4.36282907,45.08751525 4.35861606,45.08625192 4.35494114,45.07728238 4.3463717,45.07504488 4.34773707,45.0652487 4.36071279,45.05539235 4.37024377,45.05600494 4.37872964,45.05286546 4.38164448,45.0427975 4.37906791,45.03617458 4.35634117,45.03332893 4.35154346,45.02766 4.31808555,45.02993417 4.29968357,45.02003785 4.29111026,44.99732802 4.29878029,44.9887561 4.30731682,44.98588261 4.31323448,44.97958149 4.31436545,44.97316562 4.30114797,44.97104278 4.29422516,44.96680121 4.27941995,44.96670236 4.25658693,44.95987591 4.23523868,44.96780514 4.22385442,44.96287933 4.21657227,44.93357696 4.20485774,44.92762644 4.19004647,44.91418912 4.19168831,44.9121365 4.18432145,44.90832531 4.17947873,44.88651395 4.1661603,44.88194528 4.15663658,44.87397695 4.13689606,44.87405475 4.1179439,44.87811003 4.10842966,44.87793527 4.08790579,44.87033154 4.07756333,44.8698111 4.06930524,44.8676939 4.05685239,44.87206312 4.03890971,44.87276369 4.02873461,44.86616833 4.02520376,44.85100203 4.02004729,44.84586319 4.02858718,44.83461932 4.02125901,44.83036507 4.00908727,44.83462728 3.99860302,44.82357518 3.98959257,44.83133631 3.98492974,44.83169293 3.98145115,44.82596121 3.9871535,44.81638444 3.98188477,44.81167712 3.96732041,44.82017873 3.96318334,44.8297589 3.94554263,44.82434621 3.9444745,44.82101486 3.9368181,44.79809294 3.91802852,44.77885597 3.91752237,44.77572686 3.92433354,44.77097933 3.92491795,44.7696239 3.91365675,44.766539 3.90016631,44.76306592 3.89816504,44.75328619 3.89394309,44.75159164 3.87648653,44.75680012 3.87219056,44.75519536 3.86252733,44.74387248 3.8756356,44.73947496 3.87713813,44.73618578 3.86318298,44.7190807 3.86312762,44.71217548 3.86992028,44.70725146 3.86964774,44.69696268 3.88352915,44.69671771 3.88456326,44.69344121 3.87164707,44.67933634 3.88537341,44.65745732 3.89477809,44.64996294 3.89576609,44.64229316 3.89413972,44.6152877 3.90666232,44.61096322 3.90808444,44.6077014 3.90653997,44.59237276 3.91846593,44.58736759 3.91682073,44.58070997 3.92356688,44.57188481 3.9487739,44.57288659 3.96090595,44.55381227 3.96569168,44.53768216 3.97931816,44.51992532 3.97685158,44.51700323 3.98112661,44.51537179 3.9868601,44.50216744 3.98722191,44.47463359 3.99816299,44.4597976 4.01508223,44.45347624 4.02387624,44.44630077 4.03710323,44.44595204 4.04541872,44.43349476 4.03781265,44.42091793 4.05479488,44.41478791 4.0684402,44.40505961 4.05945332,44.39391121 4.04633101,44.39586419 4.04239308,44.39407402 4.04374938,44.38455454 4.05298035,44.37869605 4.05207497,44.37252902 4.05708949,44.36414472 4.05367698,44.35879401 4.05125959,44.33671638 4.03570617,44.32985115 4.04805864,44.31894948 4.05145166,44.3173237 4.06014404,44.32016597 4.07384193,44.32902636 4.10386084,44.33390556 4.10941995,44.33084284 4.11779265,44.32993887 4.1267519,44.33773356 4.14166453,44.32395917 4.1428677,44.3133509 4.1617005,44.3121543 4.1779905,44.31774254 4.18657907,44.29973545 4.216384,44.28903899 4.23405202,44.27505945 4.24513799,44.26807462 4.25890083,44.2644249 
       </coordinates> 
</LinearRing> 
</outerBoundaryIs> 
</Polygon>
 </Placemark>
</Document> 
</kml>
```

I have no problem, the feature is shown on the map.

but when i read this file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document> 
<Style id="gitesdegaule.fr"> 
<LineStyle>

                   <color>30939a9a</color>
                   <width>3</width>
                   </LineStyle>
                   <PolyStyle>
                   <color>2166738f</color>
                   </PolyStyle>
    </Style> <Placemark id="455">
 <name><![CDATA[TOTO]]></name>

               <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
               <type><![CDATA[dep]]></type>
    <styleUrl>#gitesdegaule.fr</styleUrl> 
<Polygon> 
<outerBoundaryIs> 
<LinearRing> 
<tessellate>1</tessellate> 
<coordinates>

                              4.49078404,45.23221104 4.50559101,45.23303018 4.51811524,45.24174958 4.53625982,45.23681852 4.54255203,45.24218046 4.5610247,45.24721951 4.58480191,45.24407499 4.60531508,45.25340079 4.60530462,45.26366797 4.59849348,45.26897113 4.59134794,45.27288266 4.59859706,45.28948575 4.6118888,45.29202388 4.62159418,45.29142427 4.62291558,45.29473743 4.61699707,45.30009181 4.61579882,45.31025919 4.6338438,45.31494163 4.64317694,45.31890286 4.63855316,45.32619375 4.68012988,45.34626522 4.69802319,45.34498654 4.70331032,45.34956262 4.72311135,45.35460056 4.72582584,45.36180909 4.75599728,45.3656813 4.75702289,45.37145654 4.75884778,45.38472185 4.75485043,45.39779028 4.74478279,45.40736853 4.74314597,45.42041776 4.75995346,45.43260258 4.75994808,45.43849313 4.75553574,45.44704672 4.75493212,45.45102818 4.75693557,45.45570739 4.7385421,45.47278265 4.74308844,45.47406315 4.73818222,45.48705504 4.72182757,45.49439547 4.69999732,45.47823684 4.68192909,45.47980605 4.67767901,45.48109458 4.67114076,45.47655369 4.66218578,45.48661201 4.65416401,45.48769422 4.65060257,45.49711355 4.65390491,45.49963184 4.64955158,45.51648427 4.65078586,45.52998514 4.66164659,45.53663407 4.66533161,45.54283917 4.66649143,45.54304714 4.68517621,45.55475647 4.6874991,45.55820724 4.67575573,45.56883981 4.67092194,45.56971337 4.65858737,45.56377147 4.64927375,45.56490826 4.64815725,45.5545219 4.65940094,45.54339527 4.64470376,45.54052208 4.64316126,45.54296745 4.63600237,45.54795352 4.62579924,45.56808735 4.61485831,45.57547739 4.6028616,45.57040723 4.58711037,45.57072078 4.57059967,45.58225588 4.54726149,45.58015672 4.52157864,45.57293282 4.51407047,45.57693397 4.50477475,45.5765454 4.50352247,45.58617198 4.46781408,45.58575214 4.47451695,45.5947068 4.46084052,45.60100057 4.44987671,45.60564558 4.44706995,45.61805638 4.44148878,45.62305446 4.42244408,45.62966426 4.41028424,45.63205085 4.40885989,45.63712119 4.39261031,45.65361566 4.39603517,45.65804033 4.39255068,45.66247852 4.3659202,45.67115344 4.36873236,45.67370407 4.36589129,45.68299692 4.37344684,45.69077647 4.3655162,45.69851914 4.37271335,45.70316895 4.37513943,45.71337945 4.38478413,45.72118685 4.39124722,45.73787694 4.40292476,45.74391957 4.39755475,45.75182172 4.39067665,45.75507695 4.37327083,45.74944517 4.35916069,45.75110213 4.34910141,45.77117164 4.35828752,45.77891485 4.37644958,45.78410753 4.37561751,45.80445382 4.37938419,45.80677651 4.38784034,45.80300731 4.38028193,45.81744699 4.3824649,45.82026627 4.3760349,45.82482093 4.38056885,45.82531498 4.3836978,45.83399478 4.39060126,45.83747649 4.38308316,45.84597167 4.39061473,45.8502833 4.39614026,45.85982491 4.3944707,45.86516826 4.36109365,45.86616958 4.34246865,45.87690261 4.33693619,45.89016229 4.32622429,45.89736731 4.32322056,45.90388696 4.34621534,45.91576499 4.33758097,45.91833512 4.3460197,45.92994313 4.32172436,45.94101896 4.31198864,45.94200584 4.29391226,45.95339957 4.30057483,45.95832163 4.29776074,45.96493742 4.28882289,45.97317205 4.27574232,45.9777962 4.25897507,45.98117199 4.24804289,45.98672364 4.24383957,45.997388 4.26617258,45.99754587 4.2712853,45.99231911 4.28976261,45.99564064 4.30009571,45.988894 4.3120076,46.00512986 4.31033152,46.00801321 4.30584582,46.02159224 4.30506737,46.02147512 4.28773573,46.01835911 4.28002005,46.02176977 4.26992005,46.03338416 4.26127159,46.03685799 4.25103199,46.0500212 4.25368722,46.05245052 4.2853497,46.05344698 4.29733112,46.06345144 4.30290607,46.07213249 4.30142557,46.07846278 4.31040683,46.08171869 4.31145788,46.0948465 4.30615193,46.1003564 4.30929481,46.11000177 4.31971397,46.11681585 4.322116,46.12998191 4.33274242,46.13550455 4.36158843,46.13845866 4.36922598,46.14651748 4.38180917,46.14966139 4.40824476,46.13706117 4.41736184,46.13592104 4.42365759,46.15138722 4.43116621,46.15557089 4.4385909,46.16787887 4.43338023,46.17285317 4.41431497,46.18007191 4.40635791,46.18224208 4.39617571,46.18922136 4.39687167,46.19567029 4.42296505,46.20313716 4.4217558,46.20702499 4.40674624,46.21962227 4.3880796,46.21978856 4.38841576,46.21308383 4.37476909,46.20951204 4.36335347,46.19856286 4.37349769,46.18724607 4.37080552,46.18433353 4.35851127,46.18267989 4.34664317,46.18726115 4.33490334,46.18174376 4.32664257,46.18489355 4.31641002,46.17130522 4.31183139,46.17119605 4.30287038,46.17432518 4.29028132,46.16931733 4.28243182,46.15681573 4.25319176,46.15781746 4.24865987,46.1671075 4.25340938,46.1673434 4.26191121,46.17517459 4.25814624,46.18454654 4.24536736,46.1882266 4.22657816,46.17837125 4.22499292,46.17763185 4.21955837,46.18510216 4.20621525,46.19449358 4.18922934,46.18863859 4.18493048,46.19012441 4.18485149,46.17986756 4.18675216,46.17663264 4.17813257,46.17368734 4.14332217,46.17599711 4.13384693,46.17731681 4.13339328,46.17732134 4.13263235,46.18065206 4.10383228,46.1984425 4.08357336,46.19116265 4.06755059,46.18674835 4.05997245,46.18845829 4.04983112,46.18093362 4.03114888,46.17197294 4.02748771,46.16959259 4.01804448,46.17201903 3.98852848,46.16985709 3.97149725,46.18967203 3.97257036,46.19973103 3.96516829,46.20286498 3.93621167,46.20619593 3.91710627,46.20388412 3.90945617,46.20792595 3.89013233,46.21449068 3.89750879,46.22686917 3.89739102,46.23710923 3.90740529,46.24388292 3.90876026,46.26062214 3.9037748,46.27400779 3.89953354,46.27591448 3.88695365,46.27378885 3.87767091,46.27557179 3.86889757,46.26366199 3.85055265,46.26208952 3.80768674,46.25721468 3.80269998,46.23851001 3.7782362,46.24305649 3.76928266,46.2404248 3.77335271,46.22718653 3.7849367,46.22064142 3.79408906,46.20851082 3.78866716,46.19948924 3.79050428,46.18568938 3.80786022,46.1615952 3.79162707,46.15658542 3.7933951,46.14353339 3.80125068,46.1314201 3.79348628,46.1122032 3.80283054,46.11013832 3.82129413,46.09023944 3.80560565,46.05306065 3.81370545,46.03665803 3.81594102,46.01913548 3.82471098,46.0065995 3.82734178,46.0002135 3.83207581,45.99966552 3.83173648,45.99944288 3.82448294,45.99483109 3.82322027,45.98815825 3.80972018,45.98466241 3.80017876,45.98323532 3.79068783,45.97539525 3.78171303,45.97279197 3.76002083,45.98067522 3.75520386,45.97981592 3.75063993,45.97003044 3.74207128,45.96669191 3.70961157,45.97414024 3.70180664,45.96572392 3.70450452,45.9555492 3.69416,45.94816574 3.69389159,45.9309583 3.6940178,45.9307324 3.72135,45.92274486 3.7289913,45.91414984 3.74023306,45.90776411 3.75437076,45.88603088 3.7456285,45.88416173 3.7438064,45.87813116 3.73408393,45.87126962 3.71552426,45.87058716 3.72028165,45.86174076 3.72853037,45.86268748 3.7271815,45.85618533 3.7207617,45.85112947 3.71912414,45.85006827 3.72689162,45.83026995 3.71263083,45.8012918 3.695115,45.7947011 3.69339101,45.78863317 3.70039344,45.78355599 3.72846854,45.77601195 3.73797195,45.7677824 3.73310783,45.76194268 3.73043648,45.76035707 3.72710576,45.75557878 3.7459508,45.74117335 3.75105674,45.74685781 3.75583819,45.74660974 3.7680398,45.7286698 3.78091881,45.72467303 3.77701506,45.71953096 3.78238032,45.71165023 3.7758565,45.70017756 3.77758491,45.69056601 3.79453207,45.67347279 3.80542849,45.6560512 3.8177209,45.64669614 3.82070321,45.63740799 3.82392406,45.63214338 3.83711893,45.62701204 3.85686626,45.62499932 3.86091597,45.61553082 3.86866917,45.61323791 3.88163125,45.60369048 3.90808646,45.59668998 3.93216818,45.57936472 3.93950343,45.57179317 3.94461939,45.56275392 3.95447425,45.55582657 3.94643017,45.54340415 3.95855481,45.51379079 3.96483954,45.50321872 3.96567701,45.50056395 3.97273829,45.50013378 3.98400715,45.49506462 3.98562929,45.48618012 3.96755332,45.47155064 3.97312568,45.45939932 3.96909117,45.45331965 3.97510575,45.44826959 3.98855661,45.44636881 3.99609845,45.44958903 3.99930587,45.44723713 3.99906145,45.43719838 3.98583472,45.43283979 3.96328974,45.43751133 3.96325823,45.43643097 3.93731172,45.42998695 3.91843206,45.42132709 3.91389484,45.42224667 3.90708087,45.41295465 3.8985406,45.4098176 3.89036822,45.3936646 3.89451621,45.38376197 3.89214631,45.36985001 3.89740842,45.35708382 3.90278132,45.33869736 3.90626781,45.33324816 3.91932951,45.34180452 3.91838745,45.35436532 3.93450121,45.36169725 3.9387524,45.37139623 3.94761307,45.37405019 3.9610272,45.37027082 3.97826775,45.3756958 3.98559279,45.37157925 3.99293247,45.35616958 4.00248327,45.35599445 4.01460569,45.33363343 4.01656265,45.32823058 4.0205706,45.32819411 4.02343215,45.34497168 4.03473224,45.35038803 4.03588045,45.35375438 4.04538053,45.35566527 4.05415354,45.35219705 4.0625081,45.33957375 4.07080413,45.3360547 4.07652182,45.34187131 4.0801706,45.35552423 4.09851559,45.3595783 4.10780922,45.35480397 4.10911086,45.36179726 4.12039517,45.36837595 4.15469167,45.36621756 4.15673588,45.37298659 4.14444327,45.3841085 4.16210242,45.38890677 4.18082135,45.39170092 4.20092631,45.38222954 4.22656034,45.38972368 4.23955546,45.38499682 4.24434138,45.38527698 4.25717211,45.37168832 4.27080216,45.37492065 4.27163134,45.35976373 4.28975457,45.35907018 4.29564402,45.36403638 4.30381752,45.36283383 4.30772597,45.36443631 4.30819932,45.37098695 4.33643521,45.36615975 4.34839579,45.36045982 4.36800574,45.33711309 4.36337962,45.33748473 4.33165324,45.31847732 4.35230391,45.30416276 4.3662583,45.3012825 4.36769992,45.29606858 4.36126849,45.29186931 4.35960416,45.28536043 4.35018236,45.27770267 4.37118622,45.25988603 4.37493498,45.26194731 4.38722109,45.25757187 4.39121003,45.26361916 4.41965472,45.27540139 4.4340757,45.27470404 4.44548109,45.25954447 4.45690044,45.25345239 4.47924756,45.23791196 4.48313462,45.23644652 4.49078404,45.23221104) (4.30026176,45.41350544 4.27713607,45.41762575 4.26335345,45.4160348 4.25140772,45.42159921 4.24717129,45.4299947 4.24524238,45.43638317 4.25660925,45.44238929 4.24906181,45.45322644 4.25733862,45.46105904 4.25492061,45.46392293 4.28197317,45.46603066 4.29505632,45.46341282 4.29768513,45.45377322 4.30230182,45.45311633 4.30939514,45.43430162 4.3046026,45.41485991 4.30026176,45.41350544 
    </coordinates> 
</LinearRing>
 </outerBoundaryIs>
 </Polygon> 
</Placemark>


    </Document>
 </kml>
```

The file is loaded but no feature is added on the map !  my kml is good because on openlayers it works !

can you help me please ?

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second file is [not valid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_NokiaKML2.kml) (at least the coordinates aren't)

The [first is](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_NokiaKML1.kml)

You have an extraneous ") (" between these coordinates:

```
4.49078404,45.23221104) (4.30026176,45.41350544
```